# Using Javascript to change an image on a webpage

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been working on this code for a while and for some reason I can't tell its not changing the image displayed when I press the change image button. Can anyone help?

This is the Javascript file

```js
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = "images/img/red.gif";

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "images/img/red_and_yellow.gif";

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = "images/img/green.gif";

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = "images/img/yellow.gif";

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = "images/img/red.gif";

/*------------------------------------*/

function nextImage(element) {
  var img = document.getElementById(element);

  for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    if (imgArray[i].src == img.src) // << check this
    {
      if (i === imgArray.length) {
        document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
        break;
      }
      document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i + 1].src;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the HTML.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1> Press the button to change the lights. </h1> 
  <div id="lights">
    <img src="red.gif" alt="" id="mainImg">

  </div>

  <div id="imglist">
    <a href="javascript:nextImage('mainImg')">
      <img src="next_img.png" alt="">
    </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: makes no sense to use a for loop. Id you know the start index just increment a counter. No need for all those checks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the outer `for-loop` check if the `img.src` is a part of `imgArray[i]`

```
if (imgArray[i].src.indexOf(img.src)!= -1) // notice the change here
{
  //rest of the code remains same
}
```

or simply prepend the `images/img/` to img.src before comparison

```
if (imgArray[i].src == ( "images/img/" + img.src ) ) // notice the change here
{
  //rest of the code remains same
}
```